# PHP Match error

Tags: php, echo, match

I'm using php for a profiles site that I'm working on and I need to check that the profile id doesn't equal the member id. So I have this:

```
<?php
$get_personal_sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$thisuser'";
$get_personal_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_personal_sql);
while ($personal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_personal_res)){
    $yourid = $personal['id'];
    $yourtype = $personal['type'];
    $yoursubtype = $personal['subtype'];
    $yourusername = $personal['username'];
    $youremail = $personal['email'];
    $yourname = $personal['name'];
    $youractive = $personal['active'];
    $yourpro = $personal['pro'];
    $yourdel = $personal['del'];
    $yourdate = $personal['date'];
}
?>
<?php
$get_member_sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$thismember'";
$get_member_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_member_sql);
$count_member = mysqli_num_rows($get_member_res);
if($count_member == 0){
header("Location: notfound.php");
}
while ($member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_member_res)){
    $memberid = $member['id'];
    $membertype = $member['type'];
    $membersubtype = $member['subtype'];
    $memberusername = $member['username'];
    $memberemail = $member['email'];
    $membername = $member['name'];
    $memberactive = $member['active'];
    $memberpro = $member['pro'];
    $memberdel = $member['del'];
    $memberdate = $member['date'];
}
?>
<?php
if($memberid === $yourid){
    $yourprofile = "true";
}
else{
    $yourprofile = "false";
}
?>
```

I have echoed both $memberid & $yourid in the page and they are Completely different, yet when I echo $yourprofile it displays "true". Can anyone see why this might be?

Comment: show your real code, this code has no bug

Comment: can you set $yourprofile like this: `$yourprofile = "true ".$memberid." ".$yourid;` and show us the output. It isn't really possible that they are "Completely different" in this case.

Comment: @steven Yes they were completely different but I'd put another if statement later in the page saying if($yourprofile = "true"){...} and this was obviously changing the value of $yourprofile. Fixed now but thanks anyway